# Unity Don't Load Collected items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

My Problem is that i have coins in the game (all coins are childs in one main EpmtyGameObject Prefab) and the player can collect them. but how can I make it NOT to load them again if the player has collected them,Using PlayerPrefs if possible because I want the user be able to restart the hole game (By clicking the reset game button on the settings of the game,Witch will reset PlayerPrefs) and have these coins back

(some levels have 1 coin some have more than 4 I have more than 50 levels now, so having a variable for each coin will take a lot lot of time)

Please some one help

Comment: Please clarify your question with a code example of what you have tried and what you intend to do.

Comment: I really don't know how I do it the only way I have in mind is by creating variables for each coin and assign them through the inspector and save it in PlayerPrefs when it's collected and next time the user play the level check if the coin has been collected if yes it will destroy it but that will not be efficient because in some levels I have more than 40 coins (I am using the same prefab for the coin I just duplicate coins in some levels). what I want is that if the user collected the coin and contenued to the next level,exit,etc... and come back again the collected coins should be destroyed

Answer (score 0):

i wish you explain more about your question but i answer question based on your basic explanation. maybe you receive better answers with better explanation and code examples.

if you want to have and object and have many instances from it and destroy it after some events. you should make a prefab of you object and add those prefabs to your level. for example you want to delete instances of prefab with mouse click on them. you have to attach an script to it and write that code

```
function OnMouseDown() {
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

its javascript but i think you can convert it to c# easy.